# Время, установка нового времени и даты

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как установить новое время, мне трудновато объяснить ситуацию в словах, так что давайте сразу к коду перейду:

```
var startTimeId;

var zDate = new Date();

function startTime() {
    seconds = zDate.getSeconds();
    minutes = zDate.getMinutes();

    startTimeID = setInterval(function () {

        seconds++;

        if (seconds > 59) {
            seconds = 0;
        }

        $('#someDay').html('seconds: ' + seconds + ' minutes: ' + minutes);

    }, 1000);

}

startTime();

$('#someDay').click(function () {

    clearInterval(startTimeID);

    zDate.setSeconds(45);
    zDate.setMinutes(30);

    startTime();

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/PPhnG/) рулит.

При клике, как должно быть вам видно из листинга, устанавливаются новые секунды и новые минуты, собственно говоря, здесь может быть установлено все, что имеет тип Date и может быть установлено.

Итого, что имеем? Бегущие секунды и статические минуты, впрочем, если добавить туда новые часы или дни, они тоже будут статично отображаться в окне браузера.

Вопрос, возможно ли сделать их "явно" новыми, т.е. чтобы отсчет от нового времени отображался так же как и секунды, т.е. не статично.

Хух, надеюсь, что объяснил так, что вы поймете.

П.С. секунды я сделал как инкремент ++, но это не выход, это скорее больше для понимания того, как это должно работать.

Comment: Как-то так это обычно делается.  

    function setTime(){
        var zDate = new Date(); 
        seconds = zDate.getSeconds();
        minutes = zDate.getMinutes();
         $('#someDay').html('seconds: '+seconds+' minutes: '+minutes);
    }
    
    window.setInterval(setTime, 1000);

Comment: Это не установит новую дату или время, в том-то и дело.

Comment: @Tolbase, если вы имеете ввиду установку нового времени **на компьютере пользователя** , то спешу вас разочаровать...

Comment: мне уже самому смешно, дей-но какое время на компьютере пользователя, и все же, обойти это ни как нельзя, может сделать какуе-то зависимость от секунд?

Comment: А разве у вас минуты с секундами не одновременно изменяются (через 1 сек после setSeconds и setMinutes?)У вас минуты не "статичны" они просто изменяются каждые 60 сек а когда setMinutes то через 1 сек! Что вас не устраивает?!

Comment: Статичные минуты!!! Еще раз посмотрите мой фидл и подождите минуту, они не изменяться, но это еще пол беды, хотелось при клике на элемент сделать так чтобы отсчет велся от 30 мин (не статично, чтобы это было видно), я не прошу время на пк пользователя менять, а только в самом скрипте, понимаете? Изв. если грубо комментирую, никого не хочу эксплуатировать, просто четко донести свою мысль пытаюсь.

Comment: Повторюсь  
 Сформулируйте одной ясной мыслью что Вы хотите сделать. Без отсылок на уже существующий код. Чего Вы хотите достигнуть?

Comment: без отсылок на код не получится, вот примерно это должно быть, только по всем параметрам даты (день недели, год, число, месяц, все должно быть включено). А когда кликну да div, то должно установится новая дата и от нее уже **censored** с плясками.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/PPhnG/2/

Comment: @Tolbase, я немного нюансов вам скажу: пересчитывайте время в таймаутах всегда от какой-то точки. Ща у браузеров пошли приколы непонятные (у FF в фоновой вкладке все таймауты выполняются не чаще раза в 1000ms) + таймаут может задержаться из-за тормозов системы, в итоге возникают огромные погрешности (до нес-ких мин/час), фактически 1000 превратится в 1010+ в зависимости от загрузки ОС. Так что забудьте про это прибавление секунд по таймауту. 

То есть по таймауту вы создаете новый объект Date и считаете разницу с глобальным, это даже проще должно быть. Удачи)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написал [@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow) в комментарии, Вам тут нужен другой подход. Идея вкраце такова, что вы при старке скрипта ставите "стартовую" дату например методом Date(); А по таймеру получаете тайм спан и уже его отображаете как вам угодно.

```
var startDate = Date();
...
function Interval()
{
   var timeSpan = new Date(Date() - startDate);
   ...
}
```

Почитать про работу с датами и временем в js можно например [здесь](http://on-line-teaching.com/js/js.datetime.htm)

Comment: не пойму к сожалению, сам момент того что время может куда-то убежать из-за тормозов машины мне ясен и без того, а вот что мне делать в контексте моего скрипта ни въеду никак.

Comment: Так Вам что надо? По клику чтобы время "обнулялось"? Так сделайте чтобы по клику вы выставляли глобальную переменную startDate = Date(); - это текущее время в системе клиента.

Comment: обновлялось в определенное значение и от него велся отсчет, напр. было 5 мин., стало 10.

Comment: Ну тогда вам надо добавлять ваши штрафы var timeSpan = new Date(Date() - startDate + secondsForPlus);